# Click button and get draw rectangle

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Java....I studied that we can add two things on frame... I added button and in response by clicking on button I want rectangle as output....but i don't understand that..Why i am not getting output.....

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class customizedgui5 implements ActionListener {

    JButton button;

    JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        customizedgui5 hi = new customizedgui5();

        hi.go();
    }

    public void go() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton button = new JButton("click me");

        button.addActionListener(this);

        myclass a = new myclass();

        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.getContentPane().add(a, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setSize(100, 100);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        frame.repaint();

        frame.revalidate();

    }

}

class myclass extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.orange);

        g.fillRect(20, 50, 100, 100);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

The main problem in your code is you are getting `NullPointerException` when you click the button because the reference of `frame` is `null`.

It is `null` because you've shadowed it in the constructor (basically, declared another variable of the same name within the constructor)...

```
// I'm null..
JFrame frame;

public void go() {
    // Not the same as frame above...
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

You are also going to not see any changes because of a number of reasons...

1. The `myclass` panel has no size.  With `BorderLayout`, this won't be "too" much of a problem, but...
2. You've drawing outside of the visible range of the panel.  The rectangle you are painting won't appear because it is being painted outside of the width and height of the panel.
3. The rectangle will appear before you press the button as `paintComponent` will be called to update the state of the panel once it's made visible on the screen...

The first thing you need to is provide some kind of size hints to the `BorderLayout`.  Try adding...

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(120, 150);
}
```

To `myclass`.

You also don't need to repaint the frame, what you really want to repaint is the instance of `myclass`.  Try updating `customizedgui5` so that `a` becomes a instance variable (like `frame`...

```
//...
myclass a;
//...

public void go() {

    //...
    a = new myclass();
    //...

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    a.repaint();
}
```

Now, the rectangle will still be shown the moment that the panel is made visible on the screen.  Sure you could try setting it invisible, but this will affect the layout of the frame, hiding your component to start with, so, instead, we need some kind of flag we can trip so we know when to paint the rectangle.  This is easily achieved by using a simple `boolean` variable, for example...

```
class myclass extends JPanel {

    private boolean paintRect;

    public void setPaintRect(boolean paint) {
        paintRect = paint;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(120, 150);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (paintRect) {
            g.setColor(Color.orange);
            g.fillRect(20, 50, 100, 100);
        }

    }
}
```

Then in you `actionPerformed` method, you just need to set the flag...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    a.setPaintRect(true);
}
```

You may also want to take a read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).  It will make it easier for people to read your code...

Comment: Thanks for ure reply...i really appreciate... i tried all and its all good...thank you soooo much.......but i have a doubt....!!! why i need to set boolean variable?? when i am calling "repaint" in actionPerformed() by object variable of myclass....and ActionListener is there , which can listen to button...and when button is clicked the rectangle is supposed to paint....

Comment: moreover , repaint() invokes paintComponent()

Comment: `paintComponent` will be called IMMEDIATELY (or near enough to it) when you make you ui visible for the first time.  This means that the rectangle will appear before you've clicked anything, which I assume isn't what you want. Try adding `System.out.println("painting");` in the `paintComponent` method and you will see it gets called a few times automatically...

Comment: `paintComponent` makes up part of the paint chain which is generally controlled by the `RepaintManager`.  Even when you call `repaint`, it's the `RepaintManager` the decides when and what gets painted, so you don't actually have control over when `paintComponent` will be called..

Answer (score 0):

When you click on your button, you're calling the method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)`

Take a look at what you did there. Currently, you repaint and re-validate the frame. If you want to add a rectangle to your frame, you need to do so by adding a new component to the frame that will draw the rectangle.

You could add another instance of your `myclass` `JPanel` which paints a rectangle like so:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    frame.getContentPane().add(new myclass(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

    frame.repaint();

}
```

This would add your custom rectangle-drawing panel to the North section of your `BorderLayout`. If you want to add the rectangle "on top of" your button, you should embed your button within a `JPanel`, then add the rectangle-drawing panel to that instead of your main `JFrame`

Comment: Like `myclass a = new myclass();` and `frame.getContentPane().add(a, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`?